# What is the difference between XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xmlserializer

What is the difference between XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute? Please explain both sides (i.e. serialzing and deserialzing).

Comment: Are you asking because the documentation didn't make sense to you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx

Comment: The documentation is kind of vague when comparing the two. I am starting to think that while they work similarily when serializing, there are some subtle differences when deserializing. I got it to work but I am trying to understand why one works and the other doesn't. 

It is possible that it is because my child class is derived. I haven't had time to test this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short answer - with the XmlArrayAttribute you change how the whole collection is serialized (so e.g. what is the name of the xml tag that will contain the entries), and with XmlArrayItemAttribute you control every item. Really good examples are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx

Comment: My issue is that I have created a root class and a child class. The root class has a public property that is of type List<ChildClass>. 

When I try to deserialize with no attribute, the List<ChildClass> is not populated. 

When I apply the XmlArrayAttribute to the List<ChildClass>, it is still not populated. 

When I apply the XmlArrayItemAttribute it is populated. I am wondering why the one works and the other does not.

Comment: Could you please paste (to your question) your class and an example xml?

Comment: That link has just stopped my brain from exploding.  I do dislike xmlSerialization.